# Candidate Block Bitcoin

Tags: python-3.x, blockchain, bitcoin

I am doing a custom bitcoin miner for a school project.

What I have below is the code I use to create the new hash but I do not know how to create or submit a candidate block for validation. I have tried over 40 different websites and none yeileded any results.

Also if there are any tips on how to improve code, it is greatly appreciated.

```
from hashlib import sha256
import time
from transactiongetter import inp, inpbit, out, outbit


MAX_NONCE = 100000000000

def SHA256(text):
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def mine(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_zeros):
    prefix_str = '0'*prefix_zeros
    for nonce in range(MAX_NONCE):
        text = str(block_number) + transactions + previous_hash + str(nonce)
        new_hash = SHA256(text)
        if new_hash.startswith(prefix_str):
            print(f"Yay! Successfully mined bitcoins with nonce value:{nonce}")
            return new_hash

    raise BaseException(f"Tried {MAX_NONCE} times and faield")

if __name__=='__main__':
    transactions= '''inp -> out -> inpbit'''

    difficulty= 5 # higher number more difficulty
    start = time.time()
    print("start mining")
    new_hash = mine(5,transactions,'0000000xa036944e29568d0cff17edbe038f81208fecf9a66be9a2b8321c6ec7', difficulty)
    total_time = str((time.time() - start))
    print(f"end mining. Mining took: {total_time} seconds")
    print(new_hash)
```

Comment: Where does the `transactiongetter` module come from? Is it open source code?

Comment: That is a program I made to get myself the unconfirmed transactions from https://www.blockchain.com/btc/unconfirmed-transactions as Im attempting to mine without joining a pool and using their resources / transactions